# How can I map form values to database column names when I don't know which of the form names will be passed?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, forms

I have an HTML form.
I have a MySQL table.

The form has name attributes such as "last_name," "first_name," "unique_id," etc.

The MySQL database table has the column name of "last," "first," "something_special_id," etc.

What I have done is create a new array and map it from form to table column names.  I then send back the new array, so I can then update my database.

The problem is I want to make it dynamic.

I have done this:

```
if (isset($myArray['last_name']))
{
    //Gets the current value of the form array sent in POST
    //and puts that value into the new array which is labeled
    //with the correct table column name;
    //e.g. $myArray['last_name']= "Smith";
    //now $mappedColumnNames['LAST'] is equal to "Smith";

    $mappedColumnNames['LAST'] = $myArray['last_name'];

}

if (isset($myArray['first_name']))
{
    $mappedColumnNames['FIRST'] = $myArray['first_name'];

}
if (isset($myArray['diploma']))
{
    $mappedColumnNames['DIPLOMA'] = $myArray['diploma_value_from_form'];

}
if (isset($myArray['secret_number']))
{
    $mappedColumnNames['SECRET'] = $myArray['secret_number_from_form'];

}
unset($myFormValues);
```

The `$mappedColumnNames` array is the database column names.  The `$myArray` array is the array of POST variables sent by the form.

- I do not know what they order will be each time the form is
  submitted.
- I do not know which form elements will always be
  submitted.
- I do not want to name of form attributes to be the column names of the database.
- I am not sure about changing my query in MySQL to use aliases.  For
  example, using LAST as "last_name."
- I really didn't want to change the database schema, as I'd like this
  to be "almost" database agnostic.

Is there a better way to do this than what I have done?

Here is my code to update my database:

```
$mappedColumnNames = parent::mapColumnNames($_student_search);

        //What I use now but it won't work because the form names are not the column names.
        foreach($_student_search as $key => $value)
        {
            //echo '</br>key: ' . $key . ', value: ' . $value . '</br>';
            $columns[] = $key . ' = ?';
            $new_value[$key] =  $value;
        }

        //I don't need the text input button, which occurs first
        array_shift($columns);
        array_shift($new_value);

        $sql = 'UPDATE students ';
        $sql .= ' SET ' . implode(' AND ', $columns);
        $sql .= ' WHERE student_id = ' . $new_value['student_id'];

        $this->adapter->prepare($sql);
        $this->adapter->execute($new_value);
```

EDIT:

I ended up taking the suggestions and did:

```
public function getFormNameMapping()
    {
        $realColumnNames = parent::getColumnNames('students');
        $realKeyNames  = parent::getColumnNames('students');
        return array_combine($realColumnNames, $realKeyNames);

    }

    protected function getColumnNames($myTable)
    {
        $sql = "DESCRIBE " . $myTable; //mysql only
        $this->adapter->prepare($sql);
        $this->adapter->execute();
        $results = $this->adapter->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
        return $results;
    }
```

And then:

```
        $student_model = $this->model->getStudentModel();
        $student = $student_model->findByStudentID($studentID);
        $mappedColumnNames = $student_model->getFormNameMapping();

    <input name="<?PHP echo $mappedColumnNames['FIRST']; ?>" type="text" class="text" value="<?PHP echo $student->FIRST ?>"/>
```

Thanks.

Comment: basically you want to build a query as "insert into table(" then loop through each column name ") values (" then loop through each value name")"   as long as you keep the order, and have everything that is required (e.g. not null) then you are okay

Comment: @MarshallTigerus What if I can't keep the order?  I know of no other way but to test if the value is set.

Comment: you should be able to keep the column and the value matched to one another, order otherwise doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably a better approach to consider, but for the question:

```
$crossRef = array('FIRST'=>'first_name', 'LAST'=>'last_name'); //etc...

foreach($crossRef as $key => $val) {
    if(!empty($myArray[$val])) {
        $mappedColumnNames[$key] = $myArray[$val];
    }
}
```

I extract the column names from the DB and create the form using the column names. It would be DB agnostic because it dynamically creates the form based on the DB columns.

Comment: Thanks.  What do you mean "Probably a better framework."  now sure what you mean.  What do you advise?

Comment: I hadn't given it much thought, but approach might be a better word.  I extract the column names from the DB and create the form using the column names.  So it would be DB agnostic because it dynamically creates the form based on the DB columns.

Comment: Don't you worry about the client knowing your real table names?

Comment: No. That is security through obscurity.  They only know column names, which in many apps are easy to guess (username, userid, product_id, etc.). If your app is secure, there isn't anything they can do with it.

Comment: Well, I am using prepared statements, so maybe I should just do what you're doing.  Thanks for the code.